# How to Load Balance RDS on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

How can I load balance my Relational Database on AWS so that I don't have to pay for a large server that I don't need 99% of the time? I am pretty new to AWS so I am not totally sure if this is even possible.  My app experiences surges (push notifications) that would crash the smaller DB instance class, but the larger (r5.4xlarge) isn't needed 99% of the time. How can I avoid paying for the larger instance? We are using MySQL.

This is the max CPUs utilization over the past 2 weeks for 16 CPUs and 128 GiBs RAM
[image]

Comment: Why not use serverless aurora if you "don't need 99% of the time" high load on it?

Comment: @Alex shutting down during inactivity is a separate setting in Aurora Serverless, you can disable that functionality if you want. Also, Serverless Aurora v2 scales much faster, and shutting down due to inactivity doesn't really cause issues anymore with V2.

Comment: Scaling in RDS is entirely dependent on which database engine (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc.) you are using. You haven't provided that info, so people can't really provide a full answer to your question. It sounds like you want quick scaling and a focus on cost savings, so Aurora Serverless is really the best option as long as you are OK using MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Comment: @MarkB I should have mentioned we are using MySQL

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.